# Concerned with jQuery syntax

Tags: jquery

I have textboxes with textmode as multiline in my gorm.I have to apply css to that textboxes through jQuery.For that i used following script.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $('input[type=textarea]').addClass("INPUT");

                });
```

Is there any syntax problem in above script.Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textarea is not a type of input. You can select a textarea using `$('textarea')`

Answer (score 6):

A text area isn't actually an input field. Try:

`$("textarea").addClass("INPUT");`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you say TextBox you're referring to ASP.NET TextBox, right?

If so, a TexBox with `TextMode = MultiLine` is rendered an `TextArea` HTML element.

So you need to use `$('textarea')`.